# Process creation time, shell script and system call overhead

Tags: shell-script, performance, strace, benchmark, system-programming

I have a machine dual booted with Arch Linux and Ubuntu (16.04).

I have recently started using the [Kakoune text editor](http://kakoune.org/), and noticed that its startup time is drastically different depending on which OS I am using. However I believe the underlying problem is **not** due to kakoune directly.

On startup, kakoune runs a bunch of shell scripts to enable integration with x11 and tmux, git, syntax highlighting/colorschemes, etc. This can be disabled to just load the 'vanilla' editor using the `-n` flag.

The command: `kak -e q` will start kakoune, run all startup scripts and exit immediately.

On Arch:
`time kak -e q` takes **1 second**
`time kak -n -e q` (no shell scripts) finishes in under **20 millis**.

On Ubuntu:
`time kak -e q` takes about **450 millis**
`time kak -n -e q` is again under **20 millis**

After trimming the fat and removing some of the startup scripts I did see an improvement on both OS's proportional to the amount removed.

I ran some benchmarks with [UnixBench](https://github.com/kdlucas/byte-unixbench) and found that the major differences between the two systems are seen in the 'process creation' and 'shell scripts' tests.

> The shells scripts test measures the number of times per minute a process can start and reap a set of one, two, four and eight concurrent copies of a shell scripts where the shell script applies a series of transformation to a data file.

Here is the relevant output. Units in 'loops per second' more is better:

```
Process creation (1 parallel copy of tests)
Arch:    3,822
Ubuntu:  5,297
Process creation (4 parallel copies of tests)
Arch:   18,935
Ubuntu: 30,341

Shell Scripts (1 concurrent) (1 parallel copy of tests)
Arch:      972
Ubuntu:  5,141
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent) (4 parallel copies of tests)
Arch:    7,697
Ubuntu: 24,942

Shell Scripts (8 concurrent) (1 parallel copy of tests)
Arch:      807
Ubuntu:  2,257
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent) (4 parallel copies of tests)
Arch:    1,289
Ubuntu:  3,001
```

As you can see the Ubuntu system performs much better.

I have tested using different login shells, terminal emulators, recompiling kakoune, removing unneeded software to clean up the disk, etc. I am certain this is the bottleneck.

**My question is:** what can I do to further investigate this and improve performance of the Arch Linux system to match Ubuntu? Should I look into tuning the kernel?

Additional notes:

- both systems use the same type of filesystem (ext4)
- I tend to use the Archlinux system more, and have noticed performance degrading over time
- Arch is on /dev/sda1 and is ~200GB. Ubuntu is on /dev/sda2, ~500GB. 1TB HDD.
- Arch `uname -a`: `Linux ark 4.14.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 10 11:14:50 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Ubuntu `uname -a`: `Linux sierra 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks

Comment: Do these tests use a certain shell or the system's default shell? Is `/bin/sh` linked to the same shell in both distros?

Comment: You can run an empty shell script through `strace -T ./testscript.sh` and `strace -T ./testscript.sh` and compare the output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging they use `/bin/sh`, as does kakoune. EDIT: /bin/sh points to bash in archlinux. This *might* be the reason I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu use dash as `/bin/sh`, it's somewhat faster than Bash:

```
$ time for x in {1..1000} ; do /bin/bash -c 'true' ; done                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
real    0m1.894s

$ time for x in {1..1000} ; do /bin/sh -c 'true' ; done 
real    0m1.057s
```

That's around the same area (in ratio) as your numbers.

Changing `/bin/sh` to dash instead of Bash in Debian and Ubuntu was greatly because of performance:

> The major reason to switch the default shell was efficiency. bash is an excellent full-featured shell ... However, it is rather large and slow to start up and operate by comparison with dash.

(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: A note: `LC_ALL=C /bin/bash` cuts the time from 1.537s to 0.695s on my rig, vs. 0.497s for `/bin/dash`.

Comment: @jthill, that big a difference with just that loop I used above? Curious, it doesn't really even do anything the locale would affect... And I expected that would mostly show the time used for startup. I suppose there's some overhead in loading the locales, and I can see some difference, but not nearly as large. I tried unsettting LANG and all the LC_* envvars, and then ran `(export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"; locale; time for x in {1..1000} ; do /bin/bash -c 'true' ; done )` and got 1.60 s for  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 vs. 1.48 for LC_ALL=C.

Comment: I was leaving off setting it for the non-C, getting my usual environment, `LANG=en_US.UTF8` `LC_COLLATE=C` `LC_NUMERIC=C`. Doing the unmixed en_US saves about 0.2s on the loop but yeah your exact loop, it's repeatable for me on Arch, `LC_ALL=C` cuts the startup times dramatically.  Bash 5.2.26, maybe they're working on it? Haven't checked the changelogs.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by ilkkachu, Arch uses bash for `/bin/sh`, whereas Ubuntu defaults to dash.

To further investigate this, and determine whether this explains the difference, you can configure your Ubuntu system to use bash instead and see if the benchmarks then report similar results to those obtained on Arch. To do this, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and select “No”. You can then verify that `/bin/sh` points to `bash`, and run your tests.

To restore the default, run the same command again and choose “Yes”.

If this is the reason for the difference in performance, improving Arch to match Ubuntu will be difficult. You could install dash and use that, but you’d likely run into lots of scripts which assume `/bin/sh` is bash and fail with dash — it took Debian and Ubuntu quite a long time to identify and fix all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own answer in case anyone else has the same issue:

When running the `for` loops in @ilkkachu 's answer from an **interactive bash shell** with zsh or fish as **my login shell**, the `/bin/bash` loop takes about 13 seconds. If I run the loop from a root login shell, or change **my login shell** to `/bin/bash`, I achieve results similar to those in @ilkkachu 's answer.

I presume this is because `/bin/bash` inherits its environment from the login shell (either `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/fish`), but I am not exactly sure.

In any event, I solved the issue by changing **my login shell** to `/bin/bash` and setting up my terminal to run `/bin/fish` or `/bin/zsh` as an interactive shell.